# How to define the maximum k of the kNN classifier?

Tags: classification, pattern-recognition, knn, cross-validation

I am trying to use kNN classifier to perform some supervised learning. In order to find the best number of 'k' of kNN, I used cross validation. For example, the following codes load some Matlab standard data and run the cross validation to plot various k values with respect to the cross validation error

```
load ionosphere;
[N,D] = size(X)
resp = unique(Y)

rng(8000,'twister') % for reproducibility
K = round(logspace(0,log10(N),10)); % number of neighbors
cvloss = zeros(numel(K),1);
for k=1:numel(K)
    knn = ClassificationKNN.fit(X,Y,...
        'NumNeighbors',K(k),'CrossVal','On');
    cvloss(k) = kfoldLoss(knn);
end
figure; % Plot the accuracy versus k
plot(K,cvloss);
xlabel('Number of nearest neighbors');
ylabel('10 fold classification error');
title('k-NN classification');
```

The result looks like

[image: Result]

The best k in this case is k=2 (it is not an exhaustive search). From the figure, we can see that the cross validation error goes up dramatically after k>50. It gets to a large error and become stable after k>100.

My question is what is the maximum k we should test in this kind of cross validation framework?

For example, there are two classes in the 'ionosphere' data. One class labeled as 'g' and one labeled as 'b'. There are 351 instances in total. For 'g' there are 225 cases and for 'b' there are 126 cases.

In the codes above, it chooses the largest k=351 to be tested. But should we only test from 1 to 126 or up to 225? Is there a relation between the test cases and the maximum number of k? Thanks. A.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on [crossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to choose a parameter in a classification problem, is to choose it by expertness. What you are doing certainly is not this. If your data is small enough to do a lot of classification with different values of parameters, you will do that, but to be reasonable, you need to show that the parameter you chose is not randomly chosen, you need to explain the behavior of plot you drawn.

In this case, the function is ascending, so you can tell 2 is the best choice.

In most cases you will not choose K more than 20, but there is no proof and you need to do the classification until you can proof your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `k` to be too large (i.e. too close to the number of examples), because then the `k` neighborhood of each query example contains a large fraction of the space, so the prediction depends less and less on the actual location of the query and more on the overall statistics. This explains why the performance is not good for large `k`. Your classifier essentially chooses always 'g', and gets it wrong `126/351=35%` as you see in the plot.

Theory suggests that `k` needs to grow as the number of labeled examples grow, but sub-linearly. 
When you have lots of training data, you want `k` to be large because you want to have a good estimate of the likelihood of a point near the query point to get each label. This allows to imitate the maximum aposteriori decision rule (which is optimal, assuming you know the actual distribution).

So here are some practical tips:

1. Get more data if you can. Then run the experiment again.
2. Focus on small values of `k`. My bet is that `k=3` is better than `k=2`. Usually for binary classification `k` is at least 3, and usually an odd number (to avoid ties).
3. The fact that you see that `k=2` is better does not make sense. Therefore the only case in which `k=1` is different than `k=2` is when the 2 nearest neighbors have different labels. However, in this case the decision is made either randomly or arbitrarily (e.g. always choose 'g'). It depends on the implementation of the knn algorithm. My guess is that in the algorithm you are using the decision is fixed, and that in cases of a tie it chooses 'g' which just *happens* to be more likely overall. If you switch the roles of the labels you will probably see that `k=1` is better than `k=2`.

Would be interesting to see the the plot for small values of `k` (e.g. 1 - 20).

References:
[nearest neighbor classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_classifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of neighbors to be taken into account during the classification makes your classifier a mean value choice. You only need to check the ratio of your classes to see that it is equal to the error rate.

Since you are using cross validation the k that corresponds to the minimum of your error rate is what you should select as value. In this case it is 3 if not mistaken.

Keep in mind that the cross validation parameter introduces bias in your selection of k. A more elaborate analysis is needed there, but your 10 should be fine for this case.